# Best way to estimate elasticsearch index size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch server in development and staging environment and i want estimate size of my indexes in production env, for example, with 10 millions documents

I divided the size of the index by the number of documents, but the variance between dev and staging was very large

There is a way to better estimate ?

Comment: did you take into account replicas?

Comment: in dev/staging environment its only 1 shard and no replicas... in production shards and replicas will vary